# I get java.lang.NullPointerException when getting random number

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get a random number for my Java program, but nothing happens and i get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I run the program... Here is the section of code where I get the random int, I will provide the full code after that. Thanks in advance for any help!!!

```
try {
                 PrintStream oFile = new PrintStream("Cipher.txt");
//i get the random number right below here... 
                 rot = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
                scan = new Scanner(message);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {

                cipherWord = scan.next();
                l = cipherWord.length();
                charScan = new Scanner(cipherWord);

                for(int i = 0; i < cipherWord.length(); i++){

                    cipherChar = cipherWord.charAt(i);
                    if (cipherChar == 'a') {
                        cipherChar = 'b';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'b') {
                        cipherChar = 'c';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'c') {
                        cipherChar = 'd';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'd') {
                        cipherChar = 'e';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'e') {
                        cipherChar = 'f';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'f') {
                        cipherChar = 'g';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'g') {
                        cipherChar = 'h';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'h') {
                        cipherChar = 'i';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'i') {
                        cipherChar = 'j';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'j') {
                        cipherChar = 'k';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'k') {
                        cipherChar = 'l';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'l') {
                        cipherChar = 'm';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'm') {
                        cipherChar = 'n';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'n') {
                        cipherChar = 'o';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'o') {
                        cipherChar = 'p';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'p') {
                        cipherChar = 'q';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'q') {
                        cipherChar = 'r';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'r') {
                        cipherChar = 's';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 's') {
                        cipherChar = 't';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 't') {
                        cipherChar = 'u';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'u') {
                        cipherChar = 'v';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'v') {
                        cipherChar = 'w';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'w') {
                        cipherChar = 'x';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'x') {
                        cipherChar = 'y';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'y') {
                        cipherChar = 'z';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'z') {
                        cipherChar = 'a';
                    } 
                    oFile.print(cipherChar);
                }
                oFile.print(" ");

                }
                oFile.close();
                scan.close();
                charScan.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ioe) {

                System.out.println("\n*** Print to Cipher.txt Error ***\n" + ioe);

            }
```

And here is the full program code...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CodeMaker {

public int rot;
public JScrollPane scrollArea;
public Random random;
public File Cipher;
public int l;
public File message;
public char cipherChar;
public String finalCipher;
public Scanner charScan;
public Scanner scan;
public String cipherWord;
public int z;
public int words;
public File cipherFile;
public int n;
public String cipher;
public JPanel panel;
public JButton saveButton;
public JTextArea textArea;
boolean create = true;
private JFrame frame; 
public static void main (String[] args) {
    CodeMaker gui = new CodeMaker();
    gui.start();
}

private void start() {
    frame = new JFrame("Project TrenchCoat: Cipher Creator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    makeMenus();
    makeContent();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

}

private void makeMenus() {
    JMenuBar menuBar;

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu menu;
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Cipher");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new NewListener());
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));

    menu.add(menuItem);

    JMenuItem menuitem = new JMenuItem("Read Cipher");
    menuitem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));

    menu.add(menuitem);
    menu.addSeparator();


    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
            Event.CTRL_MASK));
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

    JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem("Help");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));
    helpMenu.add(helpItem);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    JMenu aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");

    JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));
    aboutMenu.add(aboutItem);
    menuBar.add(aboutMenu);

}

private void makeContent() {
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Click a button to use its function");
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    label.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JButton createButton = new JButton("Create Cipher");
    createButton.addActionListener(new NewListener());
    createButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    createButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    createButton.setForeground(Color.green);

    panel.add(createButton);
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read Cipher");
    readButton.addActionListener(new ReadListener());
    readButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    readButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    readButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(readButton);
    JButton aboutButton = new JButton("About Cipher Creator.......");
    aboutButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    aboutButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    aboutButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(aboutButton);
    JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");
    helpButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    helpButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    helpButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(helpButton); 
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save Cipher");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new SaveListener());
    saveButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    saveButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    saveButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(saveButton); 
    textArea = new JTextArea(0,0); 
    scrollArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    panel.add(scrollArea);
    contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);







}



private class NewListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

    {
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.append("Type your message to be ciphered below, then click 'Save Cipher'. Remember, everything in the text area will be in your message, so delete this line.\n");

        }
    }
private class SaveListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        createCipher();
    }
}

private class ReadListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

            textArea.setText("");
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
            cipherFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            if (cipherFile == null) {
                return;
        }

            readCipher();
        }
        }

    private void readCipher() {

        try
        {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(cipherFile);
            while (scan.hasNext())
            {

                String cipher = scan.next();
                textArea.append(cipher);
                textArea.append("\n");


            }

            scan.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                    "I/O error in file\n\n     " +
                            cipherFile.getName() +
                            "\n\nThis program will close", 
                    "I/O Error", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    private void createCipher() {

        try
        {
            cipher = textArea.getText();
            PrintStream oFile = new PrintStream("Message.txt");
            message = new File("Message.txt");
            oFile.print(cipher);
            oFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("\n*** I/O Error ***\n" + ioe);
        }


            try {
                 PrintStream oFile = new PrintStream("Cipher.txt"); 
                 rot = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
                scan = new Scanner(message);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {

                cipherWord = scan.next();
                l = cipherWord.length();
                charScan = new Scanner(cipherWord);

                for(int i = 0; i < cipherWord.length(); i++){

                    cipherChar = cipherWord.charAt(i);
                    if (cipherChar == 'a') {
                        cipherChar = 'b';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'b') {
                        cipherChar = 'c';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'c') {
                        cipherChar = 'd';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'd') {
                        cipherChar = 'e';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'e') {
                        cipherChar = 'f';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'f') {
                        cipherChar = 'g';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'g') {
                        cipherChar = 'h';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'h') {
                        cipherChar = 'i';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'i') {
                        cipherChar = 'j';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'j') {
                        cipherChar = 'k';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'k') {
                        cipherChar = 'l';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'l') {
                        cipherChar = 'm';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'm') {
                        cipherChar = 'n';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'n') {
                        cipherChar = 'o';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'o') {
                        cipherChar = 'p';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'p') {
                        cipherChar = 'q';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'q') {
                        cipherChar = 'r';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'r') {
                        cipherChar = 's';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 's') {
                        cipherChar = 't';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 't') {
                        cipherChar = 'u';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'u') {
                        cipherChar = 'v';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'v') {
                        cipherChar = 'w';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'w') {
                        cipherChar = 'x';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'x') {
                        cipherChar = 'y';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'y') {
                        cipherChar = 'z';
                    } else if (cipherChar == 'z') {
                        cipherChar = 'a';
                    } 
                    oFile.print(cipherChar);
                }
                oFile.print(" ");

                }
                oFile.close();
                scan.close();
                charScan.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ioe) {

                System.out.println("\n*** Print to Cipher.txt Error ***\n" + ioe);

            }




            viewCipher();
    }

private void viewCipher() {
    textArea.append("\nBelow is the cipher you created.\n Now you can copy/paste in and email it to the desired recipient.");



    try
    {
        File Cipher = new File("Cipher.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Cipher);
        textArea.append("\n");

        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {

            String cipher = scan.nextLine();
            textArea.append(cipher);
            textArea.append("\n");


        }


    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                "I/O error in file\n\n     " +
                        cipherFile.getName() +
                        "\n\nThis program will close", 
                "I/O Error", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }







    }



private class ExitListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `random`?

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?  Please include the stacktrace.  As @OliCharlesworth points out, `random` isn't being initialized.  The stacktrace should include a line number that shows that it's attempt to use `random` that is causing the problem.

Comment: The huge case statement could be better written as `'a' + ((cipherChar - 'a' + 1) % 26)`.

Comment: There is way too much code here.  It's fine that you are having trouble, that's what this site is for, but if you are asking for help, you should make it as easy as possible for people to help you.  Part of that is posting only a minimal amount of code that still reproduces the problem.  It's an exercise that could also help you solve the problem yourself which is valuable practice for tougher debugging sessions in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your random generator random is not initialized. Initialize it.

```
random = new Random();
```

Btw, next time bisect the problem and post only the problematic part.

Comment: Adding on to that; the `NullPointerException` should have given you a line number in the stack trace; that should *immediately* tell you which line caused it.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to initialize your `random` variable:

```
Random random;
//later on somewhere
random = new Random();
```

Comment: The reason for this being that you can't access the Random classes' method nextInt(5) without initializing the variable random itself.

Comment: His random generator is already defined, he only needs to initialize it.

Comment: Yes, this was just an example of a properly defined and initialized variable. But thanks I will edit it

Comment: just glad op fixed his program